navbar menu hidden behind screen, how to have it show to the right?
I have the following problem with a menu on a navbar in my website using quarto:

I essentially want it to look like this, instead of being hidden:

Is there a way to change that?

you can align it right in the parent container with proper margin or padding and set their z-index.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
